# Redirect hundreds of URLs with specific pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm not sure how to properly write the directives in .htaccess to get URLs like this:

```
www.domain.com/photo/weather/p1741-high-stress.html
www.domain.com/photo/cultural-practices/p1752-thermal-convection.html
www.domain.com/photo/turf-diseases/p1748-algae-and-viruses.html
```

to:

```
www.domain.com/gallery/detail/high-stress
www.domain.com/gallery/detail/thermal-convection
www.domain.com/gallery/detail/algae-and-viruses
```

So essentially:

- changing the first segment from `photo` to `gallery`
- changing the second segment from *whatever* to `detail`
- stripping out the first part of the third segment (`p#####-`)
- stripping out the `.html` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photo/[^/]+/p\d+-(.+)\.html$ gallery/detail/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Just shows the original page/URL (or a 404 if the page no longer exists).

Comment: Other rules in the .htaccess file? Place this one before.

Comment: Is the first caret in your search expression causing it to fail? Wouldn’t that force it to match strings where your pattern starts at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Marathon55 Domain name is not in the RewriteRule test url.

Comment: So the issue I was having was an old .htaccess file in the photo directory that caused Apache to ignore the new rule. Got that resolved though and your answer did end up working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match original URLs:

```
www\.domain\.com/photo/[^/]+/p\d+-(.+?)\.html
```

Replace it with:

```
www.domain.com/gallery/detail/$1
```